# One Valid Case of Exception leaving a Destructor

Tags: c++, exception, destructor

I'm working on a simple class to manage the lifetime of a `HKEY`.

```
class Key
{
    HKEY hWin32;
public:
    Key(HKEY root, const std::wstring& subKey, REGSAM samDesired);
    Key(const Key& other);
    ~Key();
    Key& operator=(const Key& other);
    Key& swap(Key& other);
    HKEY getRawHandle() { return hWin32; };
};

 //Other Methods....

Key::~Key()
{
    LONG errorCheck
        = RegCloseKey(hWin32);
    /*
     * I know it's generally bad to allow exceptions to leave destructors,
     * but I feel that if RegCloseKey() is going to fail, the application
     * should be terminated. (Because it should never fail.)
     */
    if (errorCheck != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        WindowsApiException::Throw(errorCheck);
}
```

Is this valid reasoning? I don't see how else a failure of `RegCloseKey()` can be communicated to the callee.

Comment: As a C# programmer this makes sense.

Comment: @ChaosPandion: Does C# hate throwing exceptions from destructors as much as C++ does? I'm unsure...

Comment: Why bother throwing the exception? What could happen if `RegCloseKey` fails and you just ignore that?

Comment: I could do that Anon, but I as under the impression that ever ignoring error codes, even on functions that 'never fail' has bad karma ;)

Comment: So in other words, you're trying to decide between two things you consider "bad practice" without knowing *why* they're considered "bad practice"?

Comment: Anon -- let me put this a better way -- RegCloseKey shouldn't ever fail (AFAIK) unless you pass in something that's not a valid HKEY. If an invalid HKEY somehow gets passed to the function inside a class that's only supposed to be managing HKEYs, then I'd rather have the app crash so I can detect the bug rather than silently accept the bug and continue running with possibly corrupted data.

Comment: Exceptions leaving destructors are bad practice because of what f4 has written below. Ignoring error codes is bad practice because your application can continue running with corrupt data and fail spectacularly well away from the point of the original bug. I'm wondering if it's better to fail spectacularly here rather than allow the app to keep running.

Comment: If you want to "fail spectacularly" in your debug builds, use assertions, not exceptions.

Comment: In this case, isn't it actually possible that the application will *not* be terminated, because it might just so happen that it is this destructor where the exception originates from (and the exception is caught and handled)? An exception thrown from a destructor does *not* guarantee that the application is terminated? - Indeed use another way to terminate the program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The failure of RegCloseKey is more of an `assert` situation than an error that needs to be passed up the call chain.  You want to sit up and take notice *right away* in debug builds,

But what good is that failure information going to do the caller?  What is he supposed to do about it?

Comment: So you are saying it'd be better to replace the throw statement with an `assert(errorCheck == ERROR_SUCCESS);` line? Hmm.. that seems like a better idea.

Comment: @Billy: yes, that's what I'm saying.

Answer (score 0):

It's not *generally* bad. It *is* bad!

If an exception is thrown, the stack is unwound until a catch clause is met. If one of your Key objects is on the stack, it's destructor will be called. If it throws you have 2 exceptions at the same time. In this case terminate() is called so you won't get a chance to do anything with either one of your exceptions.

Comment: Yes, I'm well aware of exactly why allowing exceptions to leave destructors is bad. The reason I'm asking however refers specifically to RegCloseKey -- which is one of those functions that should `never fail` unless there's a bug in the application (i.e. you passed in the wrong kind of handle), and you should be able to catch those bugs during development.

Comment: I'm not sure exceptions really are a debugging tool. I'd use an assertion in this case or an other mechanism but not an exception I *might* be able to catch.

Answer (score 0):

Think about it this way - the reason ignoring an error message is bad is because if something does fail you should then be handling it and doing something with it (e.g. warn the user, retry, whatever). However in this case you're not really handling it either - you're just terminating the application (which is also bad practice).

I'd suggest that definitely having an assert to make sure that you catch anything in debug builds would be good. Writing something out using OutputDebugString might be a good idea for release builds. In that way you're not ignoring the app when an error occurs, you're noting it down but you're not terminating the app...

Terminating the app without warning or explanation is just going confuse and irritate your users.... How would you explain that to a user - "Well, something that I can't explain failed in a way that should never happen and I can't ignore it so I have to exit the application right away!"?

I guess my point is that leaking a handle, while bad, is much less bad than unexpected app shutdowns.

Comment: Apps that spew debug strings in release mode annoy me to no end. Symantec Ghost Systray Icon, I'm looking at you.

Comment: Yeah, that's a good point actually. In defence of my suggestion it just wouldn't happen that often but to be fair it's not all that useful (how often do you look at the debug log just incase something really unlikely is happenning); if the app had a log file that would be more appropriate...